# What is the power in this circuit if the voltage is doubled?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I'm actually going ahead in the book (DC Circuits) so this isn't really homework but I figured the tag was appropriate....the name of the chapter is Ohm's Law and Watt's Law.

> Problem:
>   Calculate the power dissipated in the load resistor, R, for each of the circuits.
>
> Circuit (a): V = 10V; I = 100mA; R = ?; Since I know **V** and **I** use formula **P = IV**:
>   P = IV = (100mA)(10V) = 1 W.

The next question is what I'm not sure about:

> Question: What is the power in the circuit (a) above if the voltage is doubled? (Hint: Consider the effect on current).

What I did initially was: P = IV = (100mA)(2V) = **2 W**

But then I looked at the answer and it said **4 W**, then I looked at the Hint again. Then I remembered in the book early on it said "If the voltage increases across a resistor, current will increase."

So question is: When solving problems I have to increase (or decrease) current (I) every time voltage (V) is increased (decreased) in a problem, right? How about the other way around, when increasing current (I), you need to increase voltage (V). I'm pretty sure that's how they got 4 W, but want to make sure before I head to the next section of the book.

**P = IV = (200mA)(2V) = 4 W**

Comment: Right. If you double the voltage across a resistor, that doubles the current. Double voltage times double current - four times power. If you're in the U.S. and you take a 100-watt light bulb built for 110 volts, and accidentally connect it to 220 volts, what happens? 400 watts - POP!

Comment: Thanks for the reply back! I might just have to try that with a light bulb now! :D

Comment: @MikeDunlavey - actually the resistance of a filament is [highly dependent on the temperature](http://www.plansee.com/media/images/Specific_electrical_resistance_web.png). So while I agree with your prediction of POP, in reality you will reach the melting point of the filament (at a local defect, most likely) without necessarily reaching 400 W power dissipation. Initially current can be much higher (resistance increases more than 10x from room temperature to normal operation). This means that you can't just say "2x voltage = 4x power" when it comes to light bulbs...

Comment: @Floris: You're right. I was doing back-of-the-hand physics.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I also think that's what they did. And yes, you'd also change the voltage proportionally to the current. But all of this is as long as the resistance is constant (which is what they mean when they say the circuit is the same).

A less-prone-to-mistake equation to use in these cases where the circuit is kept the same is gotten by substituting Ohms law, $V = IR$ on the power equation $P = VI$, getting $P = I^{2}R$ or $P = \frac{V^{2}}{R}$ depending which you substitute, $V$, or $I$.